# NoSuchMethodError:the getter 'photoUrl' was called on null?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/87762

i am creating an instagram clone and the source url of the circleAvatar is appear to be null
go to mygithub and try to help me please

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to provide [a minimal, complete and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). First, it's not minimal (it has 270 lines of code), it's not complete (you should "provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem *in the question itself*") and it's not reproducible (it throws "Undefined name 'currentUser'" in the mentioned line). However you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68685894/edit) with these changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should use null safety.**
This problem can be due to two possible problems.

1. in below code, the provided doc be `null`.

```
factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return User(
      id: doc['id'],
      email: doc['email'],
      username: doc['username'],
      photoUrl: doc['photoUrl'],
      displayName: doc['dispalyName'],
      bio: doc['bio'],
    );
  }
```

so replace it with:

```
factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
   if(doc!= null){
    return User(
      id: doc['id'],
      email: doc['email'],
      username: doc['username'],
      photoUrl: doc['photoUrl'],
      displayName: doc['dispalyName'],
      bio: doc['bio'],
    );
   } else { return null}
  }
```

2. the value of `currentUser` is `null` in below code:

```
leading: CircleAvatar(
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Image.network(
                  currentUser.photoUrl,
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

replace it with this one:

```
leading: CircleAvatar(
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Image.network(
                  currentUser?.photoUrl ?? "one default url",
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: thanks i have some other issues if u can help me

Comment: later i will put them here and tag u if this helps u

Comment: how i can tag it i am new here

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68699421/the-methods-cachednetworkimage-and-gettemporarydirectory-they-are-not-define